# Modify y axis on plotly

Tags: r, r-plotly

I have a plot using plotly r . As of now the variations cant be  seen that much. So in order to do so if the y-axis is 0-70% is there a way to show just 50%-70% on y axis so the variation can be seen more clearly.
Below is code I am using

```
output$plot <- renderPlotly({
  if (is.null(ab()))
    return(NULL)
  y <- list(title = "Percentange")
  x <- list(title = "Months")
  plot_ly(ab(), x = ~ Month_considered, y = ~ pct * 100,type = 'scatter', mode = 'marker',
    fill = 'tozeroy', line = list(color = 'rgb(205, 12, 24)', width = 4)) %>%layout(xaxis = x, yaxis = y)})
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't provide a reproducible example so it is hard to test, but you could try:

```
y <- list(title = "Percentage", range = c(50,70))

plot_ly(ab(), x = ~ Month_considered, y = ~ pct * 100,type = 'scatter', mode = 'marker', fill = 'tozeroy', line = list(color = 'rgb(205, 12, 24)', width = 4)) %>% layout(xaxis = x, yaxis = y)})
```

Comment: so if I want to make range dynamic this should work right `    y <- list(title = "Percentage", range = c(((ab()$pct*100)-5),45.0))
`

Comment: I assume but you don't provide an example to run it. Maybe you could provide a full reproducible shiny app.